# Joomla K2 Frontend page Modification

Tags: php, templates, joomla, edit, joomla-k2

I have K2 plugin installed and my users are able to make posts, i want to modify the "Add Item" page , where could be its possible PHP file? in com_k2 folder or...? I am totally lost !

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

John is correct, you want to use the template overrides to make your changes. This will keep your edits from being overwritten when you update your extensions. You need to make a copy of this file -

```
components/com_k2/templates/default/itemform.php
```

Then place it here -

```
templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_k2/default/itemform.php
```

Placing the file there will override the default K2 item submission form anywhere it is used on the front end. You can also use the K2 subtemplate override if you want to have access to multiple versions of the form by placing the file in your template like this -

```
templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_k2/SUBTEMPLATE NAME/itemform.php
```

If you do it this way, when you make the menu item pointing to the form, you can select from the various templates you a

Comment: I was going to use multiple templates, so i modified the original K2 code in /components/com_k2/helpers/item.php ! and also the form.php file which helped me save allot of time! :)

Comment: That's a really bad idea. The first time K2 updates your changes will be wiped out. You only need the override in the template that uses it. If it's universal change, then you are better off copying the changes to each template. Overrides will never be overwritten by extension updates.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to edit the file directly. You'll probably want to read up on [output overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides). These allow you to override the default view. Basically you'll create a folder in your template named `html` then you'll create another folder (depending on what you want to override). Then you'll create your file. The link I gave you is very helpful. It's a little too much to explain in an answer on here.

And I believe the folder you're looking for is `administrator/components/com_k2/views/item/tmpl/default.php`